# Removing debounced callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code inside of a React store:

```
  addChangeListener(cb) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, _.debounce(cb, 100));
  }

  removeChangeListener(cb) {
    _.debounce(cb).cancel();
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, cb);
  }
```

I don't believe that `removeChangeListener` is removing the `cb` because of the `_.debounce` function.  How can I use `_.debounce`, and also ensure that the proper `cb` is removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. `_.debounce` creates a new function.  So you need to do something like:

```
var debouncedCb;

addChangeListener(cb) {
  debouncedCb = _.debounce(cb, 100)
  this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, debouncedCb);
}

removeChangeListener(cb) {
  this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, debouncedCb);
  _.debounce(cb).cancel();
}
```

Depending on you're specifics, you'll probably want to attach `debouncedCb` to `cb` somehow, so that `removeChangeListener` doesn't get confused.

Comment: Thanks, ended up hashing `debouncedCB` to `cb`.